# Can we use array element as switch case in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, switch-statement, case

```
String designations[][] = { { "e", "Engineer", "20000" },
                            { "c", "Consultant", "32000" },
                            { "k", "Clerk", "12000" },
                            { "r", "Receptionist", "15000" },
                            { "m", "Manager", "40000" } };

switch (desgCode) {
        case designations[0][0]: // this line cause error
        {
            System.out.println("--"+designations[0][1].getClass());
            break;
        }
```

// Below is what I want:
I want to pass a Designation code(i.e. "e" , "c", "k", "r" or "m") and return full designation such as "Engineer" in case of "e",
"Consultant" in case of "C",
and so on

Comment: what logic would you expect if the value of `designations[0][0]` changed?

Comment: the value of designations[0][0] is not required to be changed.
as per the value of desgCode the case should match

Comment: You are missing my point.  There is no guarantee (to the compiler) that the value of `designations[0][0]` does not change.  It is now `e`, but somewhere in the code it could be changed to be `foo-bar`  It would break your `switch` statement.  But any as per the link, Java doesn't allow variables as cases in switch statements

Comment: even if I make it final. Still same problem.  Then How can I do this?